# How to print items in Lookahead/Lookbehind only?

Tags: regex

I need to extract both email and zip code in a line using PCRE regex. The line may contain other fields in arbitary order. Each field if exits, only occurs once. Regex prints result only if *both* fields exist.

I wrote this regex, but the entire line is displayed

```
^(?=.*?[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)(?=.*?\b[\d]{5}\b).*$
```

Examples:

f1  f2  11061  f3  abc@mydom.com  f4
         prints ==>         11061  abc@mydom.com

f1 f2  f4  f3  xyz@mydom.com  10018
        prints ==>         xyz@mydom.com   10018

f2 f4  10048 f3
        prints ==>         (  null  )

Is there a way to print just the matched patterns?

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
(\d{5})|([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}) << only if the input contains BOTH
```

**edited:**

```
(?:(?<zip>\d{5}).*(?<email>[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}))|(?:(?<email>[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}).*(?<zip>\d{5}))
```

group "zip" is zip

group "email" is email-address

Comment: Thanks TheHe. But I need the regex to print result, only if BOTH items are in the line.  Also zip code may follow after email and vise versa.

Comment: not correct? there is the "|"-character (logical OR)...
in which language do you use this regex and with which modifiers?
whole string vs. line-by-line?

Comment: Incorrect. That regex matches "12345". I need to print only if both email and zip code are present. I use Expresso and Google Regex testers to verify. Thanks

Comment: Hi TheHe,I am sorry if I didn't explain clearly. When I entered test data without email such as "f1  12345  f2" using your regex, 
it returns 12345. Regex should return nothing in this case since email was not present. 

Here are examples:



"f1 12345 f2 abc@mydom.com f3"      prints   12345   abc@mydom.com

"f1 f2 xyz@mydom.com  54321 f3"     prints   xyz@mydom.com  54321
   
"f1   12345  f2 "                   prints   nothing ( null )

Comment: Oops ... I just saw your new Regex, let me test later, heading to a meeting. Many thanks TheHe